# Is there an "executemany" analog for R and RSQLite?

Tags: r, sqlite

**Question**:
Is there a way to insert many rows (under 20k) into an SQLite3 table using r?

**More work**:
I have looked at similar answers, but they do not seem to speak to this:

- [Is it possible to insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database)
- [How to insert values into sqlite3 using autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294494/how-to-insert-values-into-sqlite3-using-autohotkey)
- [Is there a simple way to use RSQLite and `sqldf` with more than 999 variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026342/is-there-a-simple-way-to-use-rsqlite-and-sqldf-with-more-than-999-variables/8027913#8027913)
- [dbWriteTable operation in RSQLite become slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292861/dbwritetable-operation-in-rsqlite-become-slower)
- [Insert multiple rows in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055566/insert-multiple-rows-in-sqlite)

There is a "c command" but that is not "R".

The SQLite3 help itself doesn't seem to give a way forward:

- https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Python has "[execute many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331894/i-cant-get-pythons-executemany-for-sqlite3-to-work-properly)" which makes large inserts operate quickly.  Is there an "R" analog in RSQLite or DBI?  Is there a different library that I should use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not `?dbSendPreparedQuery`?

Comment: @joran - the help documentation doesnt talk much about prepared queries.  Can you point me to or give me a basic example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dbWriteTable` has an append argument to allow adding on to a table.  Using the built in `BOD` data frame:

```
library(RSQLite)
con <- dbConnect(SQLite())
dbWriteTable(con, "BOD", BOD) # create the table

dbWriteTable(con, "BOD", 2*BOD, append = TRUE) # add some more rows
```

Comment: This is definitely simpler than a prepared query.

Comment: And this works on full tables?  Neat!  Let me test it. (EDIT) - you rock.  Thank you @G. Grothendieck.

Answer (score 1):

there is a proper way to iterate over rows in a data.frame or tibble and insert each row one by one in a SQLite table. the easy solution with `dbWriteTable` doesn't provide much granularity in the table parametrization and `INSERT` conditions, which are oftentimes needed (e.g. to set primary and foreign keys).

example with a time series stored in a tibble with 2 columns 'times' and 'values'

1. Create table

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), db_path)

table_name <- 'my_ts'

com <- as.character(stringr::str_glue("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '{table_name}' \
                                     ('times' TEXT NOT NULL, 'values' REAL, PRIMARY KEY(times));"))

DBI::dbWithTransaction(con, {
     DBI::dbExecute(con, com)
    })
```

2. Store tibble columns as vectors

```
tb_times <- as.character(tb[['times']])
tb_values <- as.numeric(tb[['values']])
```

3. Insert rows

```
for (i in seq_along(index(tb))) {
    com <- as.character(stringr::str_glue("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO '{table_name}'(times, 'values') \
                                        VALUES('{tb_times[i]}', {tb_values[i]});"))
    DBI::dbWithTransaction(con, {
        DBI::dbExecute(con, com)
    })
}

RSQLite::dbDisconnect(con)
```

p.s. 'values' is inbetween quotes in the `INSERT` statement as it is a reserved word in SQLite