# in the R SQLite package, for the function "dbWriteTable" is there a way to decare column type?

Tags: r, sqlite

I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093292/is-there-an-executemany-analog-for-r-and-rsqlite) question.

I am able to put the whole table into the SQLite3, and am working on specifying the type.  Clearly the 'r' data.frame properties imperfectly translate to SQLite3.

Question:
Using the R SQLite package, for the "dbWriteTable" is there a way to specify the type of column, particularly for boolean and date-time?

When I try writing a posixtime column using dbWriteTable:

```
> dbWriteTable(conn=myDBcon,name = tlist[idx],value = rt1)
```

then I get the following error:

```
Error in sqliteSendQuery(conn, statement, bind.data) : 
RAW() can only be applied to a 'raw', not a 'double'
```

If I treat the posixtime as a numeric, then I do not get that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify column types with the `field.types` argument in [dbWriteTable()](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/RSQLite.pdf) which takes a character vector. Specified names correspond to table names:

```
dbWriteTable(conn=myDBcon, name = tlist[idx], value = rt1,
             field.types=list(dte="text", val="real", bool="integer"),
             append=FALSE, overwrite=TRUE, rownames=FALSE)
```

Comment: Am I looking in the wrong place in the documentation?  My help documentation does not have the detailed description.  I get dbWriteTable(conn,name,...).  Where do I get the "..." part like you did? EDIT: aha.  When I was using help it gave me "DBI" results not "RSQLite" results.  Is there a way to specify the library to search, or is it better to just start with "??" before using "?"?

Comment: The link in my answer points to a PDF. Navigate to table of contents and click the numbered page (p. 10) corresponding to `dbWriteTable()`. Scroll down (as function begins at bottom of page) and all listed arguments appear later (p. 11).

Comment: Note that the only data types in SQLite are NULL, REAL, INTEGER, TEXT and BLOB and, in particular there are no date or datetime types.  See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Also note that if the dte field is of Date class in R then it will be stored as a number (days since Epoch) despite having an SQLite type of text.  If you want it stored as text you need to convert it on the R side to a character string first.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Good points. These variables here are example placeholders for the OP to be adjusted according to specific needs.